# Static files on Apache2 (Ubuntu)

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu, bitnami

I'm running a django app on **ubuntu** with **apache2** on the **bitnami** djangostack (from aws ec2).

I can't for the life of me figure out **why my static files aren't hooking up to my project**.

1) I put my static files in **/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/myproject/myproject/static** and added to my project's httpd.conf file:

```
Alias /static "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/myproject/myproject/static"

<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/myproject/myproject/static">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

2. Thus, when i put my static files in /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/myproject/myproject/static folder, shouldn't it BE LOADED when my django template calls it??? It's clearly not, so **WHERE IS IT QUERYING STATIC FILES?** What directory does it check for static files for?

Comment: What's your STATIC_URL, and STATIC_ROOT , did you run collectstatic? what does your logfile show?

Comment: possible duplicate of [apache server cant find static files in Django project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178636/apache-server-cant-find-static-files-in-django-project)